# PHP - Connect to different servers database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing on '**server1**'.
I need to save the data processed on this server to the '**server1**' database.
However, I also need to save some data to an external '**server2**' database.

The problem is that when I connect to the database of the other server I get a fairly weird error.

Error code: **1045**

Error message: **Access denied for user 'server2-username'@'server1-name' (using password: YES)**

Why does '**server1**' appear in the error message?

To me, the message says this: "hey, I can't find the '**server2-username**' on '**server1**' database". Am I correct? Why does say that, when I'm connecting to '**server2**'?

```
$connection = new mysqli('server2-ip', 'server2-username', 'server2-password', 'server2-database');

if($connection->connect_errno) {
    echo $connection->connect_errno;
    echo $connection->connect_error;
}
```

Any idea how should I connect to '**server2**'? Or what should I check?

This is the first time I want to connect to another server database. I haven't done this yet, and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: do you use variables for the connection? if so: have you tried to output these to check if they contain the right values?

Comment: No, I'm not using variables.

Comment: "Why does 'server1' appear in the error message"...because that's the machine **from** which you're connecting to the database. It's not the name of the database server. In MySQL, you can have the same username but suffixed with a different hostname, and if you wish they can be treated as separate users with separate permissions. You have to enable the user to connect from all the different hostnames you want to allow (or you can set it to allow all). I suggest you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html

Comment: This article has a simple practical example regarding specifying different hostnames (or IP address): https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/

Comment: @ADyson Thanks! So if I understood your message correctly then basically I have to ask 'server2' administrators (I don't have access to 'server2') to allow the database connection from 'server1'?

Comment: Yes, and they need to enable it for your specific username, and ensure it has the same permissions as when it connects locally from server2.

Answer (score 0):

This error mean  **'server2-username'** try to connect from **'server1-name'** and not succeed. 
Please check permissions **user2** on **server2** for connect from remote host

Answer (score 0):

It demands an account which matches the connecting `user@hostname`, which is `server2-username@server1-name`... it's just that the web-server runs on the same host `server1-name` as the mySQLd on `server1-name`. This may appear confusing, but the hostname comes from *where* the script runs.

You'd need to add user `server2-username@server1-name` to the mySQLd on `server2-name`... and if you can't get that account set up, most commonly there's a JSON API available as a web-service; exporting/importing data to any  format would also be an option, if they wish to import themselves.

SSL tunneling could even connect through local loop-back interface `127.0.0.1` on `:3307` (the problem isn't `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, but that there is no such `user@hostname` available):

```
shell_exec("ssh -fNg -L 3307:server2-ip:3306 server2-username@server2-ip");
$connection = new mysqli('server2-ip', 'server2-username', 'server2-password', 'server2-database', 3307);
```

However, either getting that remote user account setup or using an API might rather be the suggested options, because the SSL tunnel created with `shell_exec()` might be closed at any time, which all needs to be tested & handled accordingly. The error message would at least be `server2-username@server2-name` or `server2-username@localhost`, when tunneling into it.